# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and conflicting inserts

Tags: sql, select

I want to insert a row, but if a conflict occurs (example below) I'd like the database to lock the existing row so I can log its contents for debugging purposes. I am using `READ_COMMITTED` transaction isolation.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(30),
  count INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE(name));

Thread 1:
  INSERT INTO users(username, count) VALUES('joe', 1000);
  transaction.commit();

Thread 2:
  // Insert fails due to conflict with above record
  INSERT INTO users(username, count) VALUES('joe', 0);

  // Get the conflicting row and log its properties
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'joe';
```

If the conflicting row is not locked, it may be modified by the time I check it. The only workaround I found is invoking `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'joe' FOR UPDATE` before the insert. **Is it possible way to implement this without any overhead when a conflict does not occur?**

**UPDATE**: I am **not** asking to avoid the conflict or the resulting `SQLException`. I am just asking for the conflicting row to get locked so I can look up what values triggered the conflict. Yes, I know that the conflicting record contains `joe` but I want to log all its other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a portable way of doing this and looking at [MVCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675622/14731) there is a strong indication that this cannot be implemented without a substantial performance impact.

So in conclusion: you're going to have to settle for knowing that a conflict occurred but have no way of being 100% sure of the cause (there is no thread-safe to verify).

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to eliminate the confict of a `UNIQUE` column 
when using `INSERT` of rows with unique column(s).

Trying to write SQL that never has to deal with SQL Exceptions 
is just wasted effort that always ends up creating SQL that fails 
under some conditions.

Exception handling can't be avoided when dealing with real time
multi-threaded multi-user database servers, unless you 
can afford to lock the table, do the update, and unlock the
table (which will create terrible performance when under 
heavy load of many users)

The `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT VIOLATION` Exception will ALWAYS occur on the 2nd `INSERT`,
as the two `INSERT`s in your example could be widely separated in time 
(e.g. by hours, days or weeks); Table or row locking won't change this.

This problem is one that should be solved at the GUI level anyway
as choosing a "user name" that may already be chosen by a previous
user, requires providing the "new" user with feedback  like 
"Sorry, that user name is already in use by another user", so
it would seen unlikely that handling the `UNIQUE VIOLATION` exception
can or should ever be "avoided".

In addition, there is no reason to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, since
all you need to do is `SELECT id WHERE name = newName` and see if
you get a resulting `id` or `null`;  (id == null) => user name not in use,
but even then two user could try to both get the "not in use" result
at the same time and one of the `INSERT`s could still fail.

When the `UNIQUE` exception is returned on the duplicate `INSERT`,
the second `INSERT` has failed and that record was not created, 
so there is no "duplicate" record to lock and then read after
the `UNIQUE` exception is returned on the failed `INSERT`.

Comment: -1. I'm **not** trying to avoid SQLException. All I'm asking is that when a conflict does occur, the conflicting row gets locked so I can look it up without the risk that (in the meantime) it was modified by another thread. Your approach fails to guarantee this, so I might end up logging the wrong values.

Comment: Your insisting that the confilicting row exists at all, and INSERT of rows with UNIQUE columns WILL NEVER COMPLETE AND CREATE THE CONFLICTING ROW IN THE FIRST PLACE. The very definition of UNIQUE in the SQL Standard implemented by all the relational databases i am aware of simply WILL NOT ever create the duplicate row on such an INSERT.  Yor problem is you don't get "INSERT row with UNIQUE".

Comment: You could remove the UNIQUE constraint and the your insert will work and you could then implement the UNIQUE checking with IF EXISTS(SELECT ...) and use ROLLBACK after logging as in the style described below by Noel within a transaction for each of the INSERTs.

Comment: You're still misunderstanding the question. I want to lock the conflicting row, which is **not** the same as the row I am inserting. It's the other one. The one that existed **before** the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of SQL are you usign? I'm not sure if I understand correctly your question but I think you could do this in a trigger.

In the trigger, you can view the inserted value (your conflicting row) and log it, and make a rollback. Wich means that when you insert your row, when a conflict does not occur, you don't have to commit anything, and when a conflict occurs, the log is made and the row is not inserted.

Comment: I am not using SQL Server, if that's what you're asking. Your answer fails to address the fact that the conflicting record needs to be locked. Getting its ID is not enough, as others may modify it before I look it up.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up when answering yesterday, I meant triggers. If your not usign SQL Server, what SQL are you usign? Oracle? MySQL? Microsoft Access database?

Answer (score 0):

No, most databases do not support that kind of operation.

You can do tricks like creating an explicit transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
IF EXIST(SELECT ...)
  ROLLBACK
INSERT INTO...
COMMIT
```

But that isn't exactly what you want. The only to achieve what you're asking for is to use one of the B-TREE style libraries which are a lot more low-level.

Comment: What do you mean about b-tree libraries? Is this something that lives outside of the database? Also, is `IF EXISTS(SELECT ...` portable SQL? Or is it database-specific?